# Spell correction using Keras RNN in python

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, spell-checking

I am doing spell correction using RNN, Below is the code I am using

```
from __future__ import print_function, division, unicode_literals

import os
import errno
from collections import Counter
from hashlib import sha256
import re
import json
import itertools
import logging
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import choice as random_choice, randint as random_randint, shuffle as random_shuffle, seed as random_seed, rand
from numpy import zeros as np_zeros # pylint:disable=no-name-in-module

from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Activation, TimeDistributed, Dense, RepeatVector, Dropout, recurrent
from keras.callbacks import Callback

# Set a logger for the module
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__) # Every log will use the module name
LOGGER.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

random_seed(123) # Reproducibility

class Configuration(object):
    """Dump stuff here"""
CONFIG = Configuration()
#pylint:disable=attribute-defined-outside-init
# Parameters for the model:
CONFIG.input_layers = 2
CONFIG.output_layers = 2
CONFIG.amount_of_dropout = 0.2
CONFIG.hidden_size = 500
CONFIG.initialization = "he_normal" # : Gaussian initialization scaled by fan-in (He et al., 2014)
CONFIG.number_of_chars = 100
CONFIG.max_input_len = 20
CONFIG.inverted = True

# parameters for the training:
CONFIG.batch_size = 100 # As the model changes in size, play with the batch size to best fit the process in memory
CONFIG.epochs = 500 # due to mini-epochs.
CONFIG.steps_per_epoch = 1000 # This is a mini-epoch. Using News 2013 an epoch would need to be ~60K.
CONFIG.validation_steps = 10
CONFIG.number_of_iterations = 10

dataset=pd.read_csv("input_spell.csv")
input_data=dataset['input'].tolist()
input_data1=str(input_data)
output_data=dataset['output'].tolist()
output_data1=str(output_data)


chars=list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

MIN_INPUT_LEN = 1
AMOUNT_OF_NOISE = 0.2 / CONFIG.max_input_len
CHARS = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .")

class CharacterTable(object):
    """
    Given a set of characters:
    + Encode them to a one hot integer representation
    + Decode the one hot integer representation to their character output
    + Decode a vector of probabilities to their character output
    """
    def __init__(self, chars):
        self.chars = sorted(set(chars))
        self.char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(self.chars))
        self.indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(self.chars))

    @property
    def size(self):
        """The number of chars"""
        return len(self.chars)

    def encode(self, C, maxlen):
        """Encode as one-hot"""
        X = np.zeros((maxlen, len(self.chars)), dtype=np.bool) # pylint:disable=no-member
        for i, c in enumerate(C):
            X[i, self.char_indices[c]] = 1
        return X

    def decode(self, X, calc_argmax=True):
        """Decode from one-hot"""
        if calc_argmax:
            X = X.argmax(axis=-1)
        return ''.join(self.indices_char[x] for x in X if x)
    


def _vectorize(questions, answers, ctable):
    """Vectorize the data as numpy arrays"""
    len_of_questions = len(questions)
    X = np_zeros((len_of_questions, CONFIG.max_input_len, ctable.size),dtype=int)
    print("inputchars")
    for i in range(len(questions)):
        print(i)
        sentence = questions.pop()
        print(sentence)
        for j, c in enumerate(sentence):
            print(j)
            print(c)
            try:
                X[i, j, ctable.char_indices[c]] = 1
            except KeyError:
                pass # Padding
    y = np_zeros((len_of_questions, CONFIG.max_input_len, ctable.size), dtype=int)
    print("outputchars")
    for i in range(len(answers)):
        print(i)
        sentence = answers.pop()
        print(sentence)
        for j, c in enumerate(sentence):
            try:
                y[i, j, ctable.char_indices[c]] = 1
            except KeyError:
                pass # Padding
    return X, y



def vectorize(questions, answers, chars=None):
    """Vectorize the questions and expected answers"""
    print('Vectorization...')
    chars = chars or CHARS
    ctable = CharacterTable(chars)
    print("inputdata before _vec")
    print(questions)
    X, y = _vectorize(questions, answers, ctable)
    # Explicitly set apart 10% for validation data that we never train over
    #print("input after _vec")
    #print(X)
    #print("output after _vec")
    #print(y)

    print(X.shape)
    print(y.shape)

    return  X, y, CONFIG.max_input_len, ctable

def generate_model(output_len, chars=None):
    """Generate the model"""
    print('Build model...')
    chars = chars or CHARS
    model = Sequential()
    # "Encode" the input sequence using an RNN, producing an output of hidden_size
    # note: in a situation where your input sequences have a variable length,
    # use input_shape=(None, nb_feature).
    for layer_number in range(CONFIG.input_layers):
        model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, input_shape=(None, len(chars)), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization,
                                 return_sequences=layer_number + 1 < CONFIG.input_layers))
        model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))
    # For the decoder's input, we repeat the encoded input for each time step
    model.add(RepeatVector(output_len))
    # The decoder RNN could be multiple layers stacked or a single layer
    for _ in range(CONFIG.output_layers):
        model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization))
        model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))

    # For each of step of the output sequence, decide which character should be chosen
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def iterate_training(model, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, ctable):
    """Iterative Training"""
    # Train the model each generation and show predictions against the validation dataset
    for iteration in range(1, CONFIG.number_of_iterations):
        #print()
        #print('-' * 50)
        #print('Iteration', iteration)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=CONFIG.batch_size, epochs=CONFIG.epochs,
                  validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
        #print_random_predictions(model, ctable, X_val, y_val)


def print_random_predictions(model, ctable, X_val, y_val):
    """Select 10 samples from the validation set at random so we can visualize errors"""
    print()
    for _ in range(10):
        #ind = random_randint(0, len(X_val))
        #rowX, rowy = X_val[np.array([ind])], y_val[np.array([ind])] # pylint:disable=no-member
        rowX, rowy = X_val, y_val
        preds = model.predict_classes(rowX, verbose=0)
        print("preds")
        print(preds)
        q = ctable.decode(rowX[0])
        print("q-value")
        correct = ctable.decode(rowy[0])
        print("correct")
        print(correct)
        guess = ctable.decode(preds[0], calc_argmax=False)
        print("predicted")
        print(guess)
        return guess
        

X_train,y_train, y_maxlen, ctable = vectorize(input_data, output_data, chars)
print ("y_maxlen, chars", y_maxlen, "".join(chars))
model = generate_model(y_maxlen, chars)
iterate_training(model, X_train, y_train, X_train, y_train, ctable)
for inp in X_train:
    inputarray = ctable.decode(inp)
    print(inputarray)
prediction=model.predict_classes(X_train, verbose=0)
for p in prediction:
    guess = ctable.decode(p, calc_argmax=False)
    print(guess)
```

Below is the content of file ***input_spell.csv***

```
input   output
sol     solid
kt      kit
whl     wheel
abr     abrasive
unv     universal
pp      pipe
plt     plate
accum   accumulator
```

I have taken code from  [deepspell](https://github.com/MajorTal/DeepSpell/blob/master/keras_spell.py)

Below is my prediction result for training set

```
ccumultorrrrrrrrrr
plteeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
pipeeellllllllllllll
universllllllllllll
brsiveeellllllllll
wheellllllllllllllll
kitteeeeeeeeeeeellll
solidddddddddddddddd
```

Input and output vector is of size

**Input:(8, 20, 26)**
**output:(8, 20, 26)**

so I am getting prediction result of length 20

I have a very basic understanding of RNN and LSTM

**Updating**
When i try  to visualize *model.summary()* i got

```
model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, None, 500)         1054000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, None, 500)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 500)               2002000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 500)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVecto (None, 20, 500)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 20, 500)           2002000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 20, 500)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 20, 500)           2002000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 20, 500)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 20, 26)            13026     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 20, 26)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 7,073,026
Trainable params: 7,073,026
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

can anyone tell me where i have gone wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to visualize the model by printing `model.summary()` to try and spot the error?

Comment: @MohamedElzare I have edited and included `model.summary()` in question

Comment: @RanjanaGirish have solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest double checking the `max_input_len`, `output_len`, and `y_maxlen` variables, Does your model train succesfully? What it's validation error?
If it seems to be training succesfully, then I suspect a problem with the shapes of the vectorized data of the generalization step.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue can be solve by adding padding after word if the word size is less then define size while vectorize. Thanks to
> Ranjana for this. Just add below code in _vectorize after the for loop
> as shown below:

```
for j, c in enumerate(sentence): 
    try:
        char_index_nm = ctable.char_indices[c]
        X[0, j, char_index_nm] = 1.0
    except KeyError:
        pass # Padding
#Below is the line that need to be added for space
X[0, j + 1 :, ctable.char_indices[" "]] = 1.0
```